# primefaces 3.2 menuItem bean variable not set on action

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

i have an xhtml page with menu and tab controls(with datatable) of primefaces. the datatable gets the value based on 'type' variable(in bean). On click on  each menu item an action is fired(onType("param")) and the type variable is set in bean(shown below). but now when i select a tab in tabView, the type variable is again set to null. why does this happen.

xhtml code:

```
    <h:form id="frm">
  <p:menu>
    <p:menuitem value="price losers" action='#{equityBean.onType("losers")}'/>
    <p:menuitem  value="price gainers"/>
    <p:menuitem  value="price volume"/>
  </p:menu>
  <p:tabView activeIndex="#{equityBean.activeIndex}">
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{equityBean.onChange}" update=":frm"/>
    <p:tab title="NSE">                   

      <p:dataTable value="#{equityBean.scripList}" var="scrip">
        ....                        
      </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="BSE">
      <p:dataTable value="#{equityBean.scripList}" var="scrip">
        .....
      </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
  </p:tabView>
</h:form>
```

bean code:

```
public void onType(String type)
{
    this.type=type;
}

public void onChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    exchange=event.getTab().getTitle();
}
   public List<MasterScrip> getScripList() {
      if(type!=null)
      {
       if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("losers"))
       {
        scripList=new ArrayList<MasterScrip> ();
     scripList=getScripByPriceLosers(exchange);
        return scripList;
       }
       else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("gainers"))
       {
        scripList=new ArrayList<MasterScrip> ();
     scripList=getScripByPriceLosers(exchange);
        return scripList;
       }
       else
       {
           scripList=new ArrayList<MasterScrip> ();
     scripList=getScripByVolumeType(exchange);
       return scripList;
       }
      }
      else
      {
          scripList=new ArrayList<MasterScrip> ();
     scripList=getScripByVolumeType(exchange);
       return scripList;
      }
    }
```

where am i getting wrong?

**edited(web.xml)** :

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: i made the bean viewscoped still its not working

Comment: Did you check if the bean is recreated on tab change. Set a breakpoint / log message in the bean's constructor to verify it.

Comment: yes the constructor is called on each tab change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beans declared as `@ViewScoped` sometimes behave like `@RequestScoped` beans and are recreated at each request or postback. The reason is described in this excellent blog post: [@ViewScoped fails in tag handlers](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers).

In the referenced article, there are some possible solutions listed. You could also save the value in session scope and only inject it into your view/request scoped bean.

Comment: awesome blog, but didnt solve my problem. it gives the solution to add the code to remove partial postbacks and save the viewstate through web.xml(web.xml code edited in my question), i did so but still the problem persists. where am i wrong?

Comment: I would not change the state saving mechanism. It has drawbacks as desribed by BalusC. Did you identify the tag handler that causes this issue? Is saving the variable in session not an option?

Comment: Thanks! session thing worked for me(although only in requestScope not in viewScope n i dont know why). thanks again u are a savior mate :)